# mod_pagespeed image compression with primefaces

Tags: primefaces, mod-pagespeed, graphicimage

Why does mod_pagespeed compress images rendered using `<h:graphicImage>` but not images using `<img>`.

For example:
Doesn't get compressed:

```
<img src="/resources/img/logo.png" alt="Logo" height="50" width="230" />
```

This does get compressed:

```
<h:graphicImage library="img" name="logo.png" alt="Logo"  height="50" width="230" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_pagespeed will only compress cacheable images:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/faq#not-rewriting